# Correlation between a variable and a dummy

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have a dataset in which risk appetite is measured through likert scales and a series of questions in which a choice must be made between sure win and bet (example: do you prefer to get \$ 1000 safe or have a 50% chance of getting \$ 2000?).
I have some data of those who responded, including gender.
I was asked to calculate the **correlation between gender and risk appetite**.

Now, to summarize the risk appetite, I thought of calculating the average of the likert scales (a low value equals a reduced risk appetite and vice versa), in order to reduce all the questions to a single variable and to be able to calculate the correlation with the gender. Then I could do the same thing for the answers on sure winnings or bets, reduce them to a single variable by calculating the average, and then calculate the correlation with gender.
My problem is that I cannot understand the usefulness of this question, ie what is the point of calculating the correlation between a variable and a dummy variable?
Do you think it makes sense to make such a calculation? Could it be that whoever left me with this assignment misused the term "correlation"?
Also, I just can't understand how such a value can be interpreted. Assuming that the correlation takes a value of -0.2, what could I say? That men are on average more risk-prone?

Comment: If you can do so, it would be interesting to calculate if risk appetite is a gender predictor (gender being a $\{0,1\}$ variable).

Comment: I hypothesized that women = 1, men = 2. I cannot infer because the sample size is too small (< 30 item) but I was told to compare the means and correlations across gender. How can I proceed regarding the correlation in your opinion?

Comment: Maybe you can find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation) useful